# How to display a name stored in my database SQLite in a TextView

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create a method that can display a name stored in my database SQLite in a `TextView`

Here's the method:

```
public String getCategoryName(int i)
{
    String res;

    res ="SELECT " + COL_CATEGORY_NAME + "FROM " +
    TABLE_CATEGORY + " WHERE " + COL_ID_CATEGORY +" = '" +i +"')";
    res=c.toString();
}
```

And in the **main activity :**

```
String name;
name=db.getCategoryName(i);
tv.setText(name);
```

**This method doesn't work:**

```
 07-10 10:43:14.768: E/Trace(1367): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
```

Comment: [Reference Link](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/)

Comment: what about this :

public String getCategoryName(int i)
   {
       String selectQuery ="SELECT " + COL_CATEGORY_NAME + "FROM " +
                TABLE_CATEGORY + " WHERE " + COL_ID_CATEGORY +" = '" +i +"')";

       database=DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
       Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

       return cursor.toString();
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my post [Android SQLite Database Example](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/sqlite-database-example/) you can learn form here also.

Yet,this is not right code you have to edit and then use.

// Getting single contact

```
public string getCategoryName(int id) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); // open database to perform some operation 

Cursor cursor = db.query(YOUR_TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_ID,
PARAM_1, PARAM_2, PARAM_3 }, KEY_ID + "=?",
new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
if (cursor != null)
cursor.moveToFirst();

String cat=  cursor.getString(0).toString();

cursor.close();
db.close();

return cat;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works very well 
if i want to display the PARAM_1 for example, we need to change the line of code like this :
String cat=  cursor.getString(1).toString();